# How can I convert IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType to BitMapImage UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

```
var contactStore = await ContactManager.RequestStoreAsync();

Contact Mycontact = await contactStore.GetContactAsync(contact.Id);

if (Mycontact.Thumbnail != null)
 {
  using (IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType stream = await Mycontact.Thumbnail.OpenReadAsync())
 {
  // todo: get bitmapimage
 }
}
```

I tried to use to code below to get my contact's image from UWP. My problem is: I don't know how to get a BitMap from **IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType**

How can I get it?

Comment: Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15328084/convert-irandomaccessstreamwithcontenttype-to-byte) answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType to Byte\[\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15328084/convert-irandomaccessstreamwithcontenttype-to-byte)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "BitMapImage", I'd suppose you mean [Bitmap​Image Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapimage) used in UWP. If so, you can define a [BitmapImage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapimage) by calling [SetSourceAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapsource#Windows_UI_Xaml_Media_Imaging_BitmapSource_SetSourceAsync_Windows_Storage_Streams_IRandomAccessStream_) and supplying a stream.

[SetSourceAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapsource#Windows_UI_Xaml_Media_Imaging_BitmapSource_SetSourceAsync_Windows_Storage_Streams_IRandomAccessStream_) method needs a [IRandomAccessStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.streams.irandomaccessstream) as parameter and [I​Random​Access​Stream​With​Content​Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.streams.irandomaccessstreamwithcontenttype) Interface just inherits form [IRandomAccessStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.streams.irandomaccessstream). So you can get a [BitmapImage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapimage) from [Random​Access​Stream​With​Content​Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.streams.irandomaccessstreamwithcontenttype) easily like the following:

```
if (Mycontact.Thumbnail != null)
{
    using (IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType stream = await Mycontact.Thumbnail.OpenReadAsync())
    {
        var bitmapimage = new BitmapImage();
        await bitmapimage.SetSourceAsync(stream);
        //TODO with bitmapimage
    }
}
```